# How to append element in a XML file using dom?

Tags: java, xml, dom

My XML file looks like this:

```
<Messages>
    <Contact Name="Robin" Number="8775454554">
        <Message Date="24 Jan 2012" Time="04:04">this is report1</Message>
    </Contact>
    <Contact Name="Tobin" Number="546456456">
        <Message Date="24 Jan 2012" Time="04:04">this is report2</Message>
    </Contact>
<Messages>
```

I need to check whether the 'Number' attribute of Contact element is equal to 'somenumber' and if it is, I'm required to insert one more Message element inside Contact element.

How can it be achieved using DOM? And what are the drawbacks of using DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main drawback to using a DOM is it's necessary to load the whole model into memory at once, rather than if your simply parsing the document, you can limit the data you keep in memory at one point.  This of course isn't really an issue until your processing very large XML documents.

As for the processing side of things, something like the following should work:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(is);
NodeList contacts = dom.getElementsByTagName("Contact");
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.getLength(); i++) {
    Element contact = (Element) contacts.item(i);
    String contactNumber = contact.getAttribute("Number");
    if(contactNumber.equals(somenumber)) {
        Element newMessage = dom.createElement("Message");
        // Configure the message element
        contact.appendChild(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DOM has two main disadvantages:

- It requires reading of the complete XML into a Java representation in memory. That can be both time and memory consuming
- It is a pretty verbose API, so you need to write a lot of code to achieve simple things like you're asking for.

If time and memory consumption is OK for you, but verbosity is not, you could still use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), a library that I have created to wrap standard Java DOM objects to simplify manipulation of XML. These are some examples of how you would implement your requirement with jOOX:

```
// With css-style selectors
String result1 = $(file).find("Contact[Number=somenumber]").append(
  $("<Message Date=\"25 Jan 2012\" Time=\"23:44\">this is report2</Message>")
).toString();

// With XPath
String result2 = $(file).find("//Contact[@Number = somenumber]").append(
  $("<Message Date=\"25 Jan 2012\" Time=\"23:44\">this is report2</Message>")
).toString();

// Instead of file, you can also provide your source XML in various other forms
```

Note that jOOX only wraps standard Java DOM. The underlying operations (`find()` and `append()`, as well as `$()` actually perform various DOM operations).

Answer (score 1):

You will do something to this effect.

- Get the `NodeList` of `Contact` element.
- Iterate through the `NodeList` and get `Contact` element.
- Get `Number` through `contact.getAttribute("Number")` where `contact` is of type `Element`.
- If your number equals `someNumber`, then add `Message` by calling `contact.appendChild()`. `Message` must be an element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Element class to create a new element

```
Element message = doc.createElement("Message");
message.setAttribute("message", strMessage);
```

Now add this element after whatever element you want using

```
elem.getParentNode().insertBefore(message, elem.getNextSibling());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=7) its about exactly what you want to do